# Debug C/C++ (native) a ndk build app in Android Studio?

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, android-ndk, native

I am trying to debug native code (using breakpoints) on Android Studio. As far as I know should be possible on 1.5.

The key point is that the app has been compiled using ndk build standard way, and it would be a huge task to create an Android Studio Project.

SO is there any way to attach our app to the debugger, import the symbols (so libs) and debug property.

If not what would be the minimal setup for the project, to recognize it as native and load the symbols?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Here is a similar question and similar answer
http://stackoverflow.com/a/33956159/1915327