# How to debug NDK code in android studio 3.0 on Windows

Tags: android, debugging, android-ndk

I am using AS 3.0 on Windows 10. I've already used this. [How to get breakpoint in NDK native code and debug native code in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28602260/how-to-get-breakpoint-in-ndk-native-code-and-debug-native-code-in-android-studio).

LLDB didn't work for me and VisualGDB is so difficult in project configuration and development. 
I want to know step and experience in android native development and debugging. Thank you.

Comment: I believe you will find LLDB much more reliable in AS 3.4

Comment: thanks in advance. Is it possible to debug NDK code and install updated LLDB manually on AS 3.0?

Comment: I have no idea how to set up AS 3.0 with updated tools. But mainly I don't understand what is your motivation to stay with the old version of the IDE?

Comment: I have installed latest version of LLDB on AS 3.4, but NDK debugging didn't work for me. I want your opinion and detail information for config.